# Offroad motorcycling across Australia

Tags: australia, motorcycles, off-road

Where can I find a map of off-roading areas and trails in Australia for motobike? Would it be possible to cross from Brisbane to Perth going off-road for the majority of the way? What are the laws surrounding off-road motorcycling in areas like National Parks Natural Reserves?

Comment: Everything in Australia is trying to kill you. Be very careful before setting off on a journey like this. A problem in the Outback could prove to be your last. Ever. That said, a Google search for 'Crossing the Outback on a motorcycle' throws up a number of articles written by people who've done something similar (by road or otherwise) and described some of the difficulties they've faced.

Comment: I have friends that have done this exact ride, and StackExchange isn't really the best place to get info.  Google will find you far better resources, and in particular information from people that have done it.  One way or another, it'll need a lot of planning.

Comment: I think you're aiming too high. That you haven't been able to find information on your own suggests that you have insufficient experience, in both planning and execution, to undertake this very arduous journey.

Comment: I have lived in Australia and planned a route like this. What I found was there are large stretches of NW Australia that have no petrol stations. You'll have to carry gas tanks on your motorcycle if you're really serious.